# Multiple forms for one database entry

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a dictionary that contains multiple questions `<string (question name), string (question)>` that I would like to iterate through and ask the user. Now each question MUST be presented individually within the view. However all answers must be compiled into one database(model) entry.

Currently to do this I have set up my view/controller like this: 
**Controller:**

```
//GET
public ActionResult questions(){
  Dictionary<string, string> questionsDic = ...
  return(questionsDic)
}

//POST
public ActionResult questions(FormCollection answers){
  myModel foo = new myModel();
  foreach(string key in answers.AllKeys){
    foo.GetType().GetProperty(key).SetValue(foo, answers[key], null);
  }
  using(var db = new entity()){
    db.foos.add(foo);
     db.savechanges();
  }
return RedirectToAction("index");
}
```

Now the controller works fine but the **view** gets annoyingly complicated (pseudo):

```
@model Dictionary<string, string> 
@using (Html.BeginForm()){
  @{
    string lastQuestion =  Model.Keys.Last();
    foreach(question in model){
    <div class="individualQuestion">
       <p> @model[question] </p>
       <input... @question>
       if (question == lastQuestion)
       {
         <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="questionActionButton" />
       }
       else
       {
        <input type="button" value="Next Question" class="questionActionButton"/>
       }  
   </div>
  }

 }
}
```

Then basically I use javascript to hide and show the questions so they all appear to be on their separate views. On the last question a submit button (which submits the form) appears.

So my question is, are there better ways to construct this desired functionality? The javascript part really feels like a hack. I looked into Ajax but I am not sure if that's the route I want to go... I wish there was a way to iterate over my questions dictionary and send a view for each one. Then I could compile the form submissions and do one entry into the db.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code makes my eyes tear with blood. Please start using [Strongly Typed Views](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/views/dynamic-v-strongly-typed-views) and [Html Helpers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/787320/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-on-HTML-Helpers-and). Becouse that's how you should use MVC.

About your question: don't you want to try some of **wizard plugins** or even write it yourself? Like [jWizard](http://www.dbarnes.info/jWizard/#demo) for example. That's definatly your case.

On your View, if you want to render your question more easily you can try [EditorTemplates](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-display-templates-and-editor-templates-in-asp.net-mvc.htm). You should just create `ViewModel` for your question and then create `EditorTemplate` for this model and you don't need for loop on your `View` at all!

But as a mension at the begining you should first understand all benifits and way of using **Strongly Typed Views**.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly think your current way is the best way, considering you offload everything client side so there are less trips back and forth to the server. If you feel the need to have a view per question, check out the following...

You can do a sliding expiration cache to hold your data and do the CRUD operations when the final question is answered.

Create a controller action that takes view model with a count of what question they are on and you can just return a view model with question, answer and question number of the next question, after updating the cache object with their recent answer. Something like

```
public ActionResult AnswerQuestion(QAndAViewModel vm)
{
    //update answer cache here
    //get next question by adding 1 to the question count in the view model
    return View(new QAndAViewModel { Question = "How are you?", QuestionCount = vm.QuestionCount + 1 });
}
```

Your cache object should be a Dict where int is the question count and string is the answer, this way if they hit the back button and re-submit a previous answer, you can account for that.

Anyways, here is the cache singleton that I use.

```
public class CacheSingleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<CacheSingleton> Lazy =
        new Lazy<CacheSingleton>(() => new CacheSingleton());

    public static CacheSingleton Instance
    {
        get { return Lazy.Value; }
    }

    private CacheSingleton()
    {
        _cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    }

    private readonly ObjectCache _cache;

    public object Get(string key)
    {
        var contents = _cache[key];
        return contents;
    }

    public void Add(string key, object value, bool useSlidingExpiration = true, int minutesUntilExpiration = 15)
    {
        if (value == null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key))
        {
            return;
        }

        var policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
        if (useSlidingExpiration)
        {
            policy.SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(0, minutesUntilExpiration, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(minutesUntilExpiration);
        }

        _cache.Set(key, value, policy);
    }

    public void Remove(string key)
    {
        if (_cache.Contains(key))
        {
            _cache.Remove(key);
        }
    }
}
```